# MT4 on my VPS won't send emails until I manually connect the RDP

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, azure, vps

Evening

I have a set up of my Azure Windows 2012 VPS with a static IP address to maintain the same RDP connection. This works perfectly, however, I'm running an application (MetaTrader 4) that is supposed to ping an email every four hours to confirm that said application is still running.

The said application does start by applying the `shell:start` command but it wont actually send an email until I log into the server after it automatically boots up after the weekend.

Is there a way in which the application continues to ping an email as if the VPS has never shut down in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can start the application as a service, rather than using desktop (logon) ressources. The [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/download) (Non-Sucking Service Manager) maybe helpful here.